# Replacing the last element in the array with static string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm calculating the day of the week from the API and I need to replace the last element, which will be today's day to string "Today" in an array.

For example:

I have an array `todayCal=[tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun, mon]` where mon is current date's day and I've to replace that mon with 'Today' while displaying.

my code:

```
 var weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
 var d = new Date();
 var day = d.getDay();
 var dayCal = weekdays[day];
 if(dayCal){
     console.log(dayCal[6],'weekday[6]');
     dayCal[6] = 'Today';
 }
 else {
     dayCal= weekdays[day];
 }
```

Here the last element sat is replaced with 'Today' where as I need current day to replace with 'Today'

Comment: `dayCal` is the *day* string (3 letters), so `dayCal[6]` isn't going to work

Comment: yes, that's where I got strucked on printing the lenght I'm getting as 3 .

Comment: Do you need to convert `weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];` to something like `['Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon']`  along the way? and then to `['Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Today']`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getDay()` which returns weekday as a number and replace the value in `weekdays` with `Today` using the `getDay()` returned value.

```js
var weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
weekdays[new Date().getDay()] = 'Today'
console.log(weekdays);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the value of weakdays[] array. When you do d.getDay() it gives you a 1 pass it get the value from weakdays arrays. It is something like weakdays[1] = 'Today'. like following:

```js
var weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDay();
if(day){
   weekdays[day] = 'Today'
}else{
   console.log(weekdays);
}
console.log(weekdays);
```

Answer (score -1):

please find below modified code snippet.

```
 var weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDay();
    var dayCal = weekdays[day];
    if(dayCal){
    weekdays[day] = 'Today';
    console.log(weekdays);
    }
    else{
    dayCal= weekdays[day];
    console.log(dayCal);
    }
```